# Zend Framework on Windows - 500 Error using Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, url-rewriting

I walked through this article http://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/how-to-setup-zend-framework-with-apache-on-windows/ to setup Zend Framework with Apache 2.2 on Windows 7.

I can get to existing pages - see troubleshooting section of the article.
But whenever the rewrite module kicks in I get a 500 error.
So just trying to get to / I get a 500 error.

Without any models, controllers, or views yet which view/html is supposed to come up?

Secondly, is there a way to use logging to solve this? Which log do I look at apache? php? or app specific one?

Comment: Look at apache's error.log. It's probably in the logs folder of your apache install

Comment: nothing in the error.log related to the 500 error.

Comment: I think the PHP Log has steered me down the right path. It is unable to locate the Zend Framework. Where exactly should I add the Zend Framework path to the include_path within the project structure? I really don't want to copy zf into library folder for source control reasons.

Comment: I ended up appending a path in the index.php - now it works. Since the path to my solution was in the PHP Log, do you want to add that as an answer, Mike B.

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out! You should add your own answer and accept it, all I did was suggest you check the logs :p

Comment: First thing to do is to set display_errors in your PHP config to On.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you posted yourself is not a good one. You don't want any absolute paths in your `index.php`.

You have several possible good ways of solving this:

- symlink the Zend folder into your library folder
- add the Zend folder to your PHP include path
- use a relative path starting from the APPLICATION_PATH constant while having the Zend folder directly in your library folder

All these things will work on every OS.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an Apache `mod_rewrite` configuration problems.

See the answers for similar question 
here: [500 internal server error in zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416246/500-internal-server-error-in-zend-framework)

Answer (score -1):

I found that I had forgotten to add my Zend Library files to the include path in the main index.php file. Now the include section of the index.php file looks like this:

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    // custom
    'C:\ZendFramework-1.11.11\library',
    get_include_path(),
)));
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to add an absolute path, you don't want to change this depending on the environment.

Comment: what is the right way then on Windows to make this non-absolute? I do agree its not ideal, but then again the default of putting ZF lib into the project itself seems extreme.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the system. See my answer (I will write it now).